# C POSIX thread (pthead) pthread_create() does not work after calling pthread_join()

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix

I wrote a basic example of a threaded application which doesn't seem to be working as I expect it to work. The program should print the numbers from 0 to 99 but seems to be skipping. I've tracked it down to the fact that after the `thread_join()` loop executes for the first time, the next time, the `info[k].tid` is zero. I don't know why this happens though.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    pthread_t tid;
    int i;
    int res;
} thread_info;

void *square(void *data) {
    thread_info *info = (thread_info*) data;
    info->res = info->i;
    return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    int nthread = 2;
    int lim = 100;
    int *results;

    results = calloc(lim, sizeof(int ));
    thread_info *info = calloc(nthread, sizeof(thread_info));

    for (int i=0; i<lim; i++) {
        info[i % nthread].i = i;
        pthread_create(&info[i].tid, NULL, square, info + (i%nthread));

        if (((i+1) % nthread)) {
            continue;
        }

        for (int k=0; k<nthread; k++) {
            pthread_join(info[k].tid, NULL);
        }

        for (int k=0; k<nthread; k++) {
            results[info[k].i] = info[k].res;
        }

        memset(info, 0, sizeof(thread_info) * nthread);
    }

    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", results[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _Side note:_ `results` has 100 elements but you're trying to print 1000 in the final loop

Comment: @CraigEstey That's just for the post here - I had it as 1000 in my IDE. Corrected.

Comment: A `pthread_t` isn't just an ordinal number. It is an opaque number whose value is actually a pointer to a pthreads internal thread block (e.g. similar to what you've designed). So, if it's zero, and you pass it to `pthread_join`, it will [ultimately] deref a `NULL` I cleaned your code a bit, and _now_ I don't get a segfault. But, even numbered `results` values seem to be random.

Comment: @CraigEstey I didn't get a segfault. However, after we call the `pthread_join()`, the next `pthread_create()` calls leave the `tid` as zero. Try with a `nthread = 8`. I'm surprised it doesn't segfaults or works at all to be honest! I don't understand why calling `pthread_create()` after `pthread_join()` cause this.

Answer (score 2):

The code as written is broken: here

```
for (int i=0; i<lim; i++) {
  info[i % nthread].i = i;
  pthread_create(&info[i].tid, NULL, square, info + (i%nthread));
  ...
```

you are accessing `info[i].tid` (with `i` in range `[0, 100)`, but `info` only contains 2 (`nthread`) elements. That's a buffer overflow.

Here:

```
for (int k=0; k<nthread; k++) {
    pthread_join(info[k].tid, NULL);
}
```

you are joining `info[0].tid` and `info[1].tid`. That works for `i == 0` and `i == 1`, but fails for `i == 3` due to the bug above.

You want:

```
    for (int i=0; i<lim; i++) {
        const int slot = i % nthread;
        info[slot].i = i;
        pthread_create(&info[slot].tid, NULL, square, info + slot);
```

You should also *always* check return value for all `pthread_*` functions. Doing so will save you a lot of debugging time.

For example, with this change the problem becomes clearer:

```
for (int k=0; k<nthread; k++) {
  int rc = pthread_join(info[k].tid, NULL);
  if (rc != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "pthread_join: %s\n", strerror(rc));
    abort();
  }
}
...

gcc -g -pthread thr.c && ./a.out
pthread_join: No such process
Aborted
```